# Docker container in Windows Bash ignores non-ASCII characters, work's in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, character-encoding

I'm running a Python Docker container on my Windows 10 computer. If I add Norwegian specific characters in my Python code, such as `print("båt")`, and run the container in Windows Bash, the output is `bt`. Running the same image in PowerShell outputs `båt`.

In Windows Bash, I installed the Norwegian locale to see if that made any difference:

```
sudo locale-gen nb_NO.UTF-8
sudo update-locale LANG=nb_NO.UTF-8
```

After restarting Windows Bash, I can see that the correct locale is set:

```
echo $LANG
```

returns `nb_NO.UTF-8`.

Running the container once more still outputs `bt`.

Does anyone know what may be causing the issue?

Comment: Where is your docker client and docker daemon?